# Почему MatSort работает только с датами?

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { myHTTPService } from 'src/app/services/HTTP/myhttp.service';

export interface Lead {
  firmName: String;
  address: String;
  tasks: Array<Object>;
  createdDate: Date;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lead-list',
  templateUrl: './lead-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lead-list.component.styl']
})
export class LeadListComponent implements OnInit {
  Leads: Lead[];
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firmName', 'tasks', 'address', 'createdDate'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private myHttp: myHTTPService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLeadList();
  }
  async getLeadList() {
    await this.myHttp.getHTTP('http://localhost:3000/getLeadList')
      .subscribe( (data: Lead[])=> {
        console.log(data);
        this.Leads = data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Leads);
        return this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; // Не работает
      }, err => {
        console.log('Get all Leads error: ' + err);
      });
  };
}
```

Доброго дня!
Подобная сортировка работает только с датами.
Мне необходимо сортировать не только даты, но и текстовые поля.
Хотя в [примере](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview) подобный способ работает еще и с другими параметрами.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="firmName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Название </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firmName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="tasks">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Задачи </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <div *ngFor="let x of element.tasks"> 
        <span *ngIf='x.status=="started"'>{{x.deadLineDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span> 
        <br>
        <span>{{x.deadLineDate | date: 'HH:mm'}}</span>
      </div> 
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Адрес </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="createdDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Дата создания </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: сортировка не работает с датами, если вы внимательно прочитаете документацию, то там сказано `By default, a sort header starts its sorting at asc`, что означает, что все поля сортируются дефолтным методом `Array.prototype.sort` в алфавитном порядке по возрастанию, чтобы сортировать по дате нужно провайдить кастомный `sortDataAccessor`

Comment: Да в том то и дело что сортируется только дата.
Из всех столбцов сортировка идет только в
<ng-container matColumnDef="createdDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Дата создания </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

Comment: объясните, пожалуйста, что значит "Из всех столбцов сортировка идет только ..."? остальные столбцы вообще не сортируются? например поле `tasks` где вы внутри столбца рендерите еще список сортироваться не будет

Comment: для того чтобы мне вам помочь - нужно сделать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)